# Disable 'Variable is not accessed' error in python VsCode extension

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am using python in VSCode.

When I declare a variable, it immediately highlights it in red and says

```
Variable 'x' is not accessed
```

This is too aggressive of error checking for me, and the red hurts my brain.

How can I...

1. Turn it off completely, while leaving all other linting / error checking on.
2. At least change it to an info level warning.

Thanks!!

Comment: as soon as you use `x` the red vanishes, most likely the next line use `x`

Comment: yup, which is exactly why the red bothers me. Its very normal for this case to arise during regular coding, so I don't want red screaming at me all the time.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following codes to your `settings.json`:

```
"python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": {
    "reportUnusedVariable": "none",
}
```

You can also choose the type which you want.

[image]